# possibility of jQuery document ready() function taking a very long time to execute

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, onload

My issue is that sometimes a piece of JavaScript (often Google Analytics) may take a very long time to load, although it's not important to the HTML be ready to be "traversed and manipulated". If I were to use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
});
```

would this mean that the `<p>` would not be populated till after something like Google Analytics is loaded?

Something like Google Analytics is generally not required on most websites and I have often found that I am waiting for it to load. (I don't want to use onload because [of it's unreliability](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn).)

Is there a better way or a way to say "don't wait for [...]"?

Note: I usually cannot put the code in a `<script>` tag just before the `</body>` tag because the site is based in a template. I usually can only edit the "content" of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google has actually released what they're calling [Asynchronous Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
  })();

</script>
```

This solves the problem because it will only load once the DOM is parsed and therefore you can already use everything on the page.

Comment: If you're using the current version of Google Analytics (analytics.js), be aware that [the recommended code has changed somewhat](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/#alternative_async_tracking_snippet).

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried loading Google analytics from within the ready function?  Here's a [link](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html) that discusses dynamic script loading.  Presumably you'd do this at the end after the other parts of your ready script had already executed.

Answer (score 1):

In most modern browsers you can now write:

```
<script>var _gaq = _gaq || [["_setAccount","UA-XXXXX-X"],["_trackPageview"]]; </script>
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" async></script>
```

The script will load async on most browsers, and cope with different schemes automagically..

You might like to use the longer - safer for older browsers - version:

```
<script>var _gaq = _gaq || [["_setAccount","UA-XXXXX-X"],["_trackPageview"]]; </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" async="true" defer="true"></script>
```

A few cavets:

- there's a bug in IE6 that will stop the JS from loading due to the missing protocol (see http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) but you could just add the protocol you are using.
- older browsers won't understand the "async" property so will load if either defered (after page loads) or just load it when they find it (so not async).

Answer (score -1):

This is just a guess but have you considered setTimeOut()?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   setTimeOut(function()
   {
      // Your code comes here
   }, 0); // We don't really need any delay
});
```

setTimeOut() has the nice feature of escaping the call stack, so it might solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. Just put this line at first javascript load and it works fine on IE after that:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: I don't think that will work...that's for a different purpose.