# Google Analytics and Hubspot Delay Javascript Execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

We are trying to use google analytics and hubspot on our site but they bith seem to delay the execution of the scripts on our site.

We are using jQuery and the "ready" function to delay our scripts until the page is ready.

Are there any ways we can delay the analytics scripts and have our scripts execute first?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852892/load-google-analytics-from-jquery-document-ready

Comment: And the question was answered in more general at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753514/how-to-dynamically-load-google-analytics-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option I have found is just putting this code close to the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Move the script code for GA and Hubspot into another jQuery "ready" function, but after the code you want to run first.

"ready" functions fire when the DOM is ready (the page source is parsed), but before all external resources are loaded. GA script is generally in-line, just before the closing </body> tag, so it runs before "ready" fires.